# Closed curves in 3D

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is $R^3$ a union of disjoint closed curves? (Obviously $R^3$ minus a line is). Is this a classical problem?

Comment: I don't think so. If you add a point at $\infty,$ then yes, this is the Hopf fibration of $\mathbb S^3.$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $R^3$ is the union of disjoint circles. Not just homeomorphs of circles, but actual circles. The following simple construction is quoted from M. Jonsson and J. Wästlund, "Partitions of $R^3$ into curves", Math. Scand. 83 (1998), 192-204 (see Theorem 1.1), where it is attributed to A. Szulkin, "$R^3$ is the union of disjoint circles", Amer. Math. Monthly 90 (1983), 640-641. Here is a link to the Jonsson-Wästlund paper: http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=77 You can find out about other results like this, some of them depending on the axiom of choice, by reading that paper.

> It is easy to see that it is possible to partition a two-punctured sphere into disjoint circles. Let $(x,y,z)$ be coordinates in $R^3$ and consider the union $C$ of the circles of radius $1$ in the $(x,y)$-plane centered at the points $(4k+1,0,0), k\in Z$. Then any sphere centered at the origin intersects $C$ in exactly two points. By covering each such sphere with disjoint circles, we obtain the desired partition.

Here is a picture: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/tessellation.shtml

I've been told that a partition of $R^3$ into circles was found independently and earlier, but not published, by William Thurston.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you wanted, but I can do it trivially: For every $r \in \mathbb{R}^3$, let $$C_{r}:I \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ be the map given by $C_{r}(x) = r$. That is, we let each curve be a trivial one point curve. These are all closed. Then we have that $$\mathbb{R}^3 = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}^3} C_r$$ and the union is disjoint.

Comment: Thank you. What if curves are homeomorphic to circles?

Comment: Yeah, I do not believe that is true, but have not yet been able to construct a proof. I will keep working on it.